How to entangle two separate set into one?
I have two sets of qubits where the information is encoded in amplitude. How can I entangle them into one to save qubits.
The information $k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3$ and $k'_0,k'_1,k'_2,k'_3$ are encoding in three qubit by the following method where $0<k,k'<1$
$$
\left|\psi\right>=\sum_{j=0}^3\left(\sqrt{1-k_j}\left|0\right>+\sqrt{k_j}\left|1\right>\right)\left|j\right>
$$
$$
\left|\psi'\right>=\sum_{j=0}^3\left(\sqrt{1-k'_j}\left|0\right>+\sqrt{k'_j}\left|1\right>\right)\left|j\right>
$$
It takes $2+1+2+1=6$ qubits here. We can use only $4=2+1+1$ qubits to encode the two set of information
$$
\left|\Psi\right>=\sum_{j=0}^3\left(\sqrt{1-k_j}\left|0\right>+\sqrt{k_j}\left|1\right>\right)\otimes\left(\sqrt{1-k'_j}\left|0\right>+\sqrt{k'_j}\left|1\right>\right)\left|j\right>
$$
Now, given the quantum channel $\left|\psi\right>$ and $\left|\psi'\right>$, How can I use quantum algorithm to get $\left|\Psi\right>$ from $\left|\psi\right>$ and $\left|\psi'\right>$.
